# Difference between 羞辱 and 侮辱

Tags: vocabulary

What is the difference between 羞辱 and 侮辱?
Do they have difference in terms of the contexts where they can be used, or semantically, or syntactically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 羞辱: humiliate (v); humiliation (n)

Example:

加拿大隊在女子曲棍球世界杯中**羞辱**日本隊13-0  - Team Canada **humiliates** Team Japan 13-0 in Women Hockey Would Cup

成人被打屁股是一種**羞辱** - An adult being spanked is a **humiliation**

> 侮辱: insult (v); insult (n)

Example:

不要用這種謊話去**侮辱**人們的智慧 - Don't use such lies to **insult** people's wisdom

把那人比作豬是對豬的**侮辱** - It is an **insult** to the pig to compare that person to a pig

羞 has the meaning of 'shame' In a typical hockey game, the score total is around 3-4 goals by both teams, losing 13-0 is a humiliation/ shame. Only children would be spanked by adults, an adult being spanked is a humiliation/ shame

Both 侮 and 辱 mean 'insult'

侮辱 = 'insult'

Basically, an insult (侮辱) makes you feel offended/ angry; A humiliation (羞辱) makes you feel belittled/ humiliated/ angry

*羞辱 (n) is similar to 恥辱 (n: humiliation; shame), but 恥辱 cannot be used as a verb*

*Being naked cause people to feel shame, to strip someone naked is more than a 侮辱. It is a 羞辱; Calling someone names is a 侮辱 but not always a 羞辱, e.g. I wouldn't consider '你這殺人兇手' (You murderer) a 羞辱, but I would consider '你這説謊者'(you liar) as one*

Comment: 加拿大隊在女子曲棍球世界杯中羞辱日本隊13-0. I'd not use 羞辱 in such a case and I don't recall seeing 羞辱 being used in such a case. Being defeated is not a 羞辱. You are trying to fit Chinese into English.

Comment: 以日本冰球隊五比零大破中國隊的世界級水凖，輸十三球是一次羞辱沒錯，如果是 3-1 or 4-2 敗陣，那才算正常賽果，畢竟日本隊曾經在奧運擊敗美國奪冠，不該大敗至雙位數

Answer (score 0):

I am a native speaker. My opinions come from my daily life, which I think may help you. And I also found my opinions different from the last answer. I do not know the reasons. But if the opinions from last answer come from some notebooks or notes, please follow them because they can help you get higher marks in a test.
"羞辱" and "侮辱" are actually almost the same words in our daily life. And they can be both used as nouns or verbs.
If you still want to know what the excat differences between the two words, we can figure out by their forms.
The character "羞" in word "羞辱" means making people shy when it used as a verb.
The character "侮" in word "侮辱" means making people offended when it used as a verb.
That's all and you may find that it is still difficult to identify what behaviors only make you shy and what only make you offended because they always make you feel both of them. That is the fact.
So do not care about their differences and you can use one of them as you want. (I would like you to use "侮辱" because "羞辱" was usually used in spoken language.)
And there is a point that I want to mentioned, which may help you understand some traditional Chinese movies. That is when Chinese people want to say a female was raped unfortunately, they may replaced the word "rape" by the word "侮辱" when they are talking about. This replacement always ease the embarrassment.

Comment: Quote: "I am a native speaker'. This statement doesn't make your opinion more valuable than mine.  'shy'(羞) is caused by 'shame' (恥) , and being  'shamed' is a  'humiliation'.  We usually replace 被強姦(raped) with 被污辱 (defiled) or 被強暴  (violated) or 被侵犯 (assaulted), not 被羞辱 (humiliated) or 被侮辱 (insulted)

Comment: I felt this answer almost correct. 羞辱 is rare used today. And it would be main difference.

Comment: @TangHo this question discuses difference between 侮辱 and 羞辱. Not 污辱.

Comment: [羞辱](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E7%BE%9E%E8%BE%B1) About 33,200,000 results (0.62 seconds)

Comment: @tsh I was replying whx's statement about avoiding the term 'raped' and replace it with '侮辱' instead, which  is obviously not correct

Comment: @TangHo [羞辱](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_zh-CN&hl=zh-CN&tbs=lr%3Alang_1zh-CN&q=%E7%BE%9E%E8%BE%B1) 29,800,000: you may only find out the actual usage of this word (not search result from dictionary) from 3rd page; [侮辱](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_zh-CN&hl=zh-CN&tbs=lr%3Alang_1zh-CN&q=%E4%BE%AE%E8%BE%B1) 68,400,000: You can find out the word used from 2nd result.

Comment: @TangHo I want to give an apology to you if my words offend you. But the reason why I say "I am a native speaker" is not try to make my opinion more valuable than yours. Just as what I mentioned in my statement, I just want to make sure that other people will not easily use my opinion in some strict exams. Because there are always some differences between theory and reality. For the usage of "侮辱“ about "rape", you can believe me at all.

Answer (score 0):

"羞辱" and "侮辱" are a pair of 同义词 but are different in 词义轻重.

> 有些同义词之间存在词义轻重的差别(e.g. "请求""恳求")……有些同义词之间存在用法或搭配上的区别(e.g. "坚定""坚强")……有些同义词所指范围有差别(e.g. "时代""时期")……有些同义词存在集体和个体的不同(e.g. "布匹""布")……还有些同义词在语体风格上存在差异(e.g. "父亲""爸爸")……
>
> ——《语文》（七年级上册）, People's Educaiton Press, 2016, Beijing

"羞辱" and "侮辱" are different in 词义轻重. Let's take a look at 《现代汉语词典》（第7版）:

> 【羞辱】①[名]耻辱。②[动]使受耻辱。

> 【侮辱】[动]使对方人格或名誉受到损害，蒙受耻辱。

So, in my opinion, **"侮辱" is more aggressive**. In other words, **侮辱的词义比羞辱重**.

Also, "羞辱" means to insult the other person to **make the other person feel ashamed**.

*`Happy Chinese New Year!`*